# CSS filters - sometimes working, sometimes not?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

I'm on the verge of pulling my hair out over this.

Here I have a block of perfectly functioning CSS:

```
#admin .block.mode.off
{
    opacity: 0.25;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25);
}
```

Meanwhile... Internet Explorer 8 couldn't care less about my filter declarations here:

```
#admin .drop .tabs
{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#admin .drop .tab
{
    margin-right: 4px;
}
#admin .drop .tab.off
{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
}
#admin .drop .tab.off:hover
{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #fff;
}
#admin .drop .tab.on
{
    cursor: default;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #fff;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#fff, strength=4)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#fff, strength=4);
}
```

My document shows in IE8 Standards, and I am assuming the developer tools are a load of tuna, because the functioning block shows up in its CSS tab as:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25); opacity: 0.25
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8), you should try giving `#admin .drop .tab` hasLayout. I usually do this with `zoom:1` **but** it looks like IE8 doesn't let that trigger hasLayout anymore, and we're supposed to use `height:1%` (or [any height declaration other than auto](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#prop)).

Comment: `height:1%` didn't work, but the link you provided had `display:inline-block` which worked a treat. Thanks :)

Comment: That's good to know. According to Microsoft, these sort of hacks shouldn't even be needed with IE8, and I've found extremely little in the way of updated reports online.