# Can you determine hasLayout in IE8's developer toolbar?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools, haslayout

There was a lot of talk that IE8 was supposed to fix/remove hasLayout. [Doesn't seem to have happened](http://jhop.me/browsers/ie8/haslayout-true), though it's not usually an issue.

The problem is that [when it does crop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8) there doesn't seem to be a way for IE8's developer toolbar to tell you hasLayout is being applied, as it used to do in IE7's developer toolbar.

Does anyone have a workaround? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the developer toolbar is not telling you that it's there, have you tried using the console to explicitly query the property? That is, using `console.log` (or whatever the IE developer toolbar equivalent is). So: `console.log(whateverObject.hasLayout)`? I realize this has more to do with Javascript, but I think this could qualify as a workaround ;)

Comment: It may indeed. Will try to try it out.

Comment: Just tested. `el.currentStyle.hasLayout` does work in the console.