# Animations failing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtbSY/)

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin that will allow us to add entrance and exit animations in the mark up.

I have the entrance animations working in Chrome and Firefox, but they are having no effect in IE7 or IE8

The animation is performed by

`animate({'top':posData.top+'px',
          'left': posData.left+'px',
          'opacity': 1}, 
         speed)`

or a varient of it (dependant on the required direction). posData is being logged to console so you can see the possible values. `speed` is set at the start of the plugin.

Comment: If you get any solution please post it here. It will help others who face same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Have answered myself below, hope it helps someone.

Comment: You can also accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a combination these factors:

- Elements needed to hasLayout
- Needed to use filter: alpha(opacity=70); for opacity to work properly
- Chrome doesn't seem to like uppercase letters in `data` attributes, which caused me to remove them in the JavaScript. Chrome and Firefox where happy with that, but IE insisted that the cases matched, so changing the `data-` attributes in the HTML to be lowercase, and making sure their JS counterparts matched.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and IE7 doesn't support CSS2 - `opacity`, you will need `filter: alpha(opacity=70);`. Please read more details [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html).

In your jsFiddle, you are changing the opacity of div. As IE8 and IE7 doesn't support `opacity`, you don't see any animation.

**EDIT**

Check this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8) post on SO. It mentions about `hasLayout` which solved the problem.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it, if you set the Opacity to 0 with jQuery `.css()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/UtbSY/1/

```
$('.animate').anim().css({"opacity": 0});
```

jQuery is using the right opacity filter for the browser in question.

Or you could use the filters in the CSS directly i guess, as mentioned by Amar... (But then the CSS Validation fails)