# Assigning color to div in CSS

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery.reveals.js plugin. 
the following colors specified in css

```
#fff 
#000
```

are being interpreted differently on different browsers. 

Getting the following output on firefox,chrome,and IE 9 ( and above)
[image: The corner of reveal box showing faint dark and more dark]

however I am getting some unexpected result with IE8
[image: The corner of reveal box without proper colors]

I guess above problem is because the color specified in css in only 3 digits i.e. `#fff` and `#000`. 
How can I fix this for IE8

Comment: Isn't the latter expected, when you're given `#FFF` and `#000`?

Comment: I uploaded two images here. Unable to see them on submitting my question.

Comment: @arxanas: no expecting the first output.

Comment: Why would you expect the first, if you haven't specified any transparency, etc.? The only colors are `#FFF` and `#000`, yet you get a light gray.

Comment: the problem is not in color, but in transparency setting

Comment: I am pretty sure this is an issue with IE8 and its handling of transparency. This question may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: this ic the css .reveal-modal-bg { 
 position: fixed; 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 z-index: 100;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
 left: 0; 
}
 it also has opacity specified as .4

Comment: I tried to make use of   `filter:alpha(opacity=40);` but even this one failed.

Comment: Have you considered using the [jquery UI modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)? It is really simple to use and since it is a part of the the jquery UI, you know it will continue to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like the IE8 one is correct, and the modern browsers are interpreting it to what looks like `#000;` but with some transparency, is there a setting of `opacity: 0.5;` somewhere that IE is ignoring and good browsers are doing??

Comment: .reveal-modal-bg { 
 position: fixed; 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 z-index: 100;
 display: none;
 top: 0;
 left: 0; 
}
there is the opacity of 0.4

Comment: There we go then, @veer7, make the opacity work in IE, or remove it completely to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Specify the color in six characters, or perhaps better yet specify the color as an `rgba` value.

Comment: The css is provided by jquery.reveals plugin. What six character colors could be used to get the effect as in result1 (snapshot1)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because before IE9, IE's png handling was horribly flawed. If you look into the plugin's asset folder you will find a `modal-gloss.png`. Now when you opacity animate a sem-transparent in IE before IE9 it will loose its transparency.

Try disabling animation with

```
 $(...).reveal({ animation: 'none'});
```

Answer (score 0):

the colors are displaying properly. I think the problem is with `opacity`.

**[Here](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)** you can read about CSS Transparency Settings for All Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`.

[**More about RGBA**](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Answer (score 0):

Stick to using the standard as intended without leaving guesswork for the browser. Meaning define in hex as `#RRGGBB` not `#RGB`. You can switch color value schemes (like to RGB) but that should not be your issue.

This link shows you examples of each color value scheme and talks about browser compatibility:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use or cite w3schools.  See [this page](http://www.w3fools.com) for reasons and details.