# Opacity isn't working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I've been scratching my head for about 3 hours now trying to figure out why the opacity CSS property isn't working for my site in IE8.

It works in IE7 and IE9+ but IE8 wont take to it.

The CSS itself is fine, I did a test on another site and it worked without problem so it just seems to be on this site...

Here is a [reference URL](http://www.robotwp.com/overseas/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Opacity CSS not working in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1948194/1763929).

Comment: It already "has layout" with it's absolute positioning

Comment: You should post some relevant code. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1):

here's my solution for you 
`background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7fffffff,endColorstr=#7fffffff);
zoom: 1;`