# IE background with filter opacity

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
figure figcaption {
    position:absolute;
    top: -65px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
    zoom: 1;
    width: 195px;
    height: 65px;
}
```

for some reason the background is not appearing on IE 8. Rest of the browsers are working fine.

Comment: Are you using a shim for HTML5 tags?

Comment: correct, I'm using shim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Initial Considerations:**

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

```
-moz-opacity: 0.70;
opacity:.70;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
```

**References:**

[Opacity CSS not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8)

**Internet Explorer Dev Center**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/616b7ee2-fdd3-48d9-9485-28608517afc1/ie-8-progiddximagetransformmicrosoftalphaopacity90-with-rollovers-does-not-work?forum=iewebdevelopment

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532967(v=vs.85).aspx

**Alternative Considerations:**

You might want to try and experiment with the online [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) app. I've found it to be incredibly helpful when trying to deal with browser versions and compatibility issues regarding not just gradients but backgrounds and their sometimes hard to remember properties.

```
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b3000000', endColorstr='#b3000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

All Code Taken From ColorZilla: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+100&0.7+0,0.7+100;Custom