# Loading spinner works on Chrome and FF but not on IE

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I got a simple MVC `@HTML.BeginForm` with the ID of `SimpleSpinForm` that does stuff. When I click on a submit button i'm showing a loading GIF that spinns while the form get submitted. It works perfectly on Chrome and FF but in IE it just stands still. Any suggestions how I can make it work on a simple way?

My DIV that holds the gif:

```
<div id="myLoadingElement" style="display: none">
    <img src="/Content/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

My Script that runs when button clicks:

```
<script>
    $("#SimpleSpinForm").submit(function (e) {
        $(".MainDiv").css("opacity", 0.9).fadeIn(300, function () {
            $("#myLoadingElement").show();
        });         
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Might be an opacity in css problem .Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: @RohitArora I've read that article and I also tried without the opacity thing, but the spinner wont spin at all. :(

Comment: For me it is working in IE 11, here is the JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/b90ua5w7/2/. Can you tell us which version of IE it is not working.

Comment: @ramiramilu I'm using IE 11, haven't tried on lower versions yet. Wierd that it works on your jsfiddle but not on my site.

Comment: So there might be some CSS specific to IE which might be blocking the loading image. check that, probably in layout. Also do check for Developer tools if there are any errors.

Comment: @ramiramilu I don't get any errors, and I do see the image, but it just is there, no action at all. I'll investigate it alittle further, maybe need to update my jQuery version? I'm using  version 1.10.2.

Comment: @ramiramilu A funny part is, the spinner works perfectly untill I but the display: none style on me div.

I also tried to use `$("#myLoadingElement").css("display", "inline-block");` instead of `$("#myLoadingElement").show();` but with no success.

Comment: I think it is the problem with JQuery version, can you try with `Jquery 1.11.0`, it is working fine for me. When i try with `JQuery 1.10.1`, it is not working.

Comment: @ramiramilu And now I've noticed that it stops to work as soon as I click on a submit button. Hmm. Wierd :(

Comment: Were you able to solve this with `JQuery 1.11.0`?

Comment: @ramiramilu I tried with the jQuery version `1.11.0` but still nothing. I've also tried without any script and i removed the `display: none` styling and noticed that as soon as I submit the form the loading image just freezes and the site loads as normally.

Comment: with `JQuery 1.11.0`, is this the expected behavior - https://jsfiddle.net/b90ua5w7/4/

Comment: I didn't really managed to fix it, so I implemented [Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) and it works well :)

Comment: From experience (no citation...) IE has an issue with all animated GIFs when the content is redrawing/reloading.   Add a delay (eg `Thread.Sleep(500)`) the post action to confirm this: while the page is posting (data being sent+processing) the animation works fine, but as soon as the browser starts receiving data, the animation stops.  If it's a large response then this can take longer than the initial request and so appears to never animate.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for the useful information! But right now the Spin.js works well for us!