# Css animation doesn't work in internet explorer, changing opacity

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation

Css animation doesn't work in internet explorer, version 11 for sure.
All the other browsers animate it perfectly good. Here is a website: http://susannahpryce.esy.es

I checked through firebug in IE, it reads the code with no erroers, so i don't know why it doesn't work, i'm using IE 11.

And here is my code

```
body .main .header-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left; }
    body .main .header-box .slide-area {
      margin: 0 9%; }
      body .main .header-box .slide-area #pic1 {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -webkit-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -ms-animation-duration: 60s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
        -ms-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -ms-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-duration: 60s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -moz-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
      body .main .header-box .slide-area #pic2 {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 4;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -webkit-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -ms-animation-duration: 60s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 20s;
        -ms-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -ms-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-duration: 60s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 20s;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -moz-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
      body .main .header-box .slide-area #pic3 {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -webkit-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -ms-animation-duration: 60s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
        -ms-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -ms-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        -moz-animation-duration: 60s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -moz-animation-name: slide-fade;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
      body .main .header-box .slide-area #pic4 {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2; }
  @-webkit-keyframes slide-fade {
  0% {
  opacity: 1; }
  5% {
  opacity: 0; }
  50% {
  opacity: 0; }
  55% {
  opacity: 1; }
  100% {
  opacity: 1; } }
  @-ms-keyframes slide-fade {
  0% {
  opacity: 1; }
  5% {
  opacity: 0; }
  50% {
  opacity: 0; }
  55% {
  opacity: 1; }
  100% {
  opacity: 1; } }
  @-moz-keyframes slide-fade {
  0% {
  opacity: 1; }
  5% {
  opacity: 0; }
  50% {
  opacity: 0; }
  55% {
  opacity: 1; }
  100% {
  opacity: 1; } }
```

Comment: It's great that you have the browser prefixes but you should always include the normal rule. Example `animation-duration: 60s;`

Comment: As far as I know,IE doesn't use prefixes for animation any more...if ever - http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation

Comment: Also note `IE10 and IE11 do not support CSS animations inside media queries.` This is in the known issues tab of Paulie_D's link. Your animation for this is inside of media queries. Try to take the animation css out of media query and see if it works. The images does not animate at all for me on IE 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the animation css out of the media query. I did a simple copy and paste and edited the css a little bit to make it work. As stated here http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation (thanks to Paulie_D) in the known issues tab

> IE10 and IE11 do not support CSS animations inside media queries.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmfj0tk7/

```
  <div class="header-box">
      <div class="slide-area">
         <img id="pic1" src="http://susannahpryce.esy.es/wp-content/themes/sue/pics/hq-1-optimized.jpg" />
         <img id="pic2" src="http://susannahpryce.esy.es/wp-content/themes/sue/pics/hq-2-optimized.jpg" />
         <img id="pic3" src="http://susannahpryce.esy.es/wp-content/themes/sue/pics/hq-3-optimized.jpg" />
         <img id="pic4" src="http://susannahpryce.esy.es/wp-content/themes/sue/pics/hq-4-optimized.jpg" />
      </div>

      <div class="slide-area_480">
      </div>

      <div class="slide-area_640">
      </div>

   </div>
```

You should also put the normal css rules in your file, as in without prefixes. Modern browsers should not need the prefixes and in the future, the prefixes should go away at some point... for this animation stuff anyway

Answer (score 1):

> historically IE doesn't apply several styles to elements that don't
>   "have layout."
>
> see: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8) is a question that was asked regarding opacity in IE.