# ArcGIS JS API SetOpacity not working in IE8

Tags: css, google-maps, mapping, opacity, arcgis-js-api

I Wrote a mapping application using ArcGIS js api 3.10.
I have a graphics layer and have a slider for the user to update its opacity.  I am using the setOpacity method.
All other browsers work except for Internet Explorer 8.
Has anyone resolved this issue without changing the document mode (my app is in an iFrame so it has to run in IE8 mode).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It is clearly mentioned in **`ArcGIS JS API`** Documentation that **`setOpacity`** method is not supported by ***Internet Explorer***..

[image]

For more detail please [click here...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html#setopacity)

**Edited[9/Jan/17]:-**

I had to implement similar functionality with feature layer I used **`setOpacity`** method only then I get to know IE8 doesn't support precisely opacity feature.

Hoping these info will help you :)

Comment: Thanks @developerr .  I understand that it is clearly written in ESRI's doc for 3.19 but that does not mean that it does not work for the version of the lib that I am using.  As I mentioned before, I am using version 3.10 of the lib.  Not sure if ESRI made a change or not but it does work for IE very well, just not for IE8, that is why I wanted to throw the question out there.  Hopefully someone came up with an alternate way of updating a layer's opacity and can help me out.

Comment: seems like you are hurt from -1 of your question.. just to let you know i didn't do that.. cool man it happens... And you didn't mentioned in your question like you already knew that,  so that was a general info just to help hopefully.

Comment: I was just doing some more finding....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948176/opacity-css-not-working-in-ie8  you might be knowing this just in case...

Comment: Thanks for the additional help.  I will see what that last link can do for me.  And no worries for the -1, my initial downvote is because I typically come on here for help that i can't get from the docs (of course we can all search it)...your last comment sounds very useful though :)