# Setting opacity with jquery not working in IE8, but works in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

My code:

```
$('.diff a').css('opacity', .5);
```

Works in IE7, firefox, and chrome, correctly making the anchor elements appear faded, but not in IE8.

I'm using jquery 1.4.4

EDIT: Here is a test page showing problem http://jsfiddle.net/KUJYF/

Comment: @Robert doctype is `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. BTW, I found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452868/opacity-in-ie8-works-on-p-but-not-on-a.

Comment: @Kyle did that solution not work (setting `display: inline-block`)? If you can't figure it out, I'll defer to: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: @Kyle I just tested in IE8 using `display: inline-block` and it appeared to work. So, good job finding the answer yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using opacity at all?  Why not just use a lighter color to simulate the effect and not have the overhead the opacity property introduces.

Comment: yea i could do that, opacity would've been easier than redefining different lighter versions of my styles for :hover, :visited, etc.

Comment: You could also use a microsoft specific alpha filter: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/a/aa121306.htm

Comment: I would recommend using styles, it's faster and cleaner then a jquery application of an opacity filter to mimic what the styles are intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this same situation while trying to animate opacity for fading in and out a `span` element.  Under IE7, animating the `span` worked flawlessly.  Under IE9, same story.  But, under IE8, there was no animation.

Thanks to the comments to the original question posed above, I found that by setting the CSS style of the span to `inline-block`, animation started working in IE8, which leads me to believe that IE8 may not support opacity on inline elements (at least, not the way that jQuery 1.4.4 implemented it).

Here's the sample I used for testing:  http://jsfiddle.net/ddYuJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use fadeto

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: Hey, do you get any JS error? Can you provide more details? Maybe the URL of your website

Comment: That doesn't set opacity, it animates to a defined value.